# IIS Not Working with VS 2013

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm getting the following error after installing VS2013:

> Service Unavailable HTTP 503

The earlier version of IIS is working with an application pool ASP.Net 4.0. This uses the 4.0 framework. I believe the new version uses the 4.5.1 framework. So the application pool might get a conflict. So when I go through the IIS manager dashboard I noticed that the application pool is getting stopped automatically. So I manually restarted and tried again. Whenever the application starts this application pool get stopped automatically. I don't know why this happening?

Please could you help to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you publishing using IIS-Local-Filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quiet sure whether it works for you, but i had the similar problem once, **registering the FrameWork with the IIS Manager resolved my problem.**

Below are the commands to run depending on 64-bit/32-bit OS version installed in your system

**%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i**

Note: 
1. Please remember to replace the "v4.0.30319" with your current version installed.
2. You should run the above commands as a Administrator(better if you logged in as a administrator).